# Uncaught TypeError: getUsername(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript

I must complete the following code snippet, based on the snippet comments, so it will run on the site  cs-dy.myshopify.com

In the code below, I should implement the function `getUsename()`. 
The result should be a greeting message with the user's name in it.
I need to test the code on page load.

Notes:
The code will run on `'window.onload'`
I'm only allowed to change the code inside the `getUsername()` function
I should get the user name from the object key: `DY.CS.username`

```
function getUsername() {
    //write code here to get the value of DY.CS.username
}

getUsername().then(function(userName) {
  alert('Welcome '+userName+'!');
});
```

I can get value by using `console.log(DY.CS.username);`

and I can make the function `getUsername()` return the value:

```
function getUsername() {
    //TODO write your code here to get the value of DY.CS.username
    var userName = '';
    if(DY && DY.CS) {
       return userName = DY.CS.username;
    }
}
```

but when it comes to the inline function expressions, it spits out errors like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: getUsername(...).then is not a function
    at <anonymous>:10:15
```

This is the function, but I'm not allowed to change that:

```
getUsername().then(function(userName) {
  alert('Welcome '+userName+'!');
});
```

(I'm only allowed to change the code inside the `getUsername()` function).

So, I wonder what I'm doing wrong?

The result should be an alert saying "Welcome John Bearyon!"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to return a `Promise` or any `thenable` from `getUsername`

Comment: Your `getUsername` function must return an object with a `then` function that itself takes a function and calls it with a value. The most common object that uses this pattern is a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `getUsername` seems like it should be a [JavaScript `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
function getUsername() {
    if (DY && DY.CS) {
        return Promise.resolve(DY.CS.username);
    }

    return Promise.reject()
}
```

keep in mind that `void` (or, perhaps a more JavaScript-y way of saying that is `undefined`) is not a valid return value from a function whose return type is `Promise`. Implicit returns (no return) or explicit `return;` statements return `undefined`.

Consider the flow of your current method:

```
# psuedocode

if DY is defined and CS exists on DY
  return DY.CS.username
else
  ... ?
```

the `else ...?` represents the implicit return. `undefined#then` is not a function. You still have to return a Promise. It can resolve to `undefined`.

The idiomatic way of handling something like this would be to `reject` (as I've done above), but if you want the same behaviour you have now with Promises, you have to resolve `undefined`.

```
function getUsername() {
    if (DY && DY.CS) {
        return Promise.resolve(DY.CS.username);
    }

    return Promise.resolve()
}
```

There's no such thing as an implicit `undefined` return using promises.

That said, if you're using `async/await`, implicit returns have the same behaviour

```
async function getUsername() {
    if (DY && DY.CS) return DY.CS.userName;
}
```

the return type is `Promise<string | void>`